# To what does a 2D array points to?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

That's might be a dumb question, but I was reading a book and they splattered to me this code

```
int arr[6][8];
int *ptr = &arr[0][0];
*(ptr+8) = 12; // arr[1][0]
printf("%d\n", arr[1][0]);
```

Now... I get why this pointer points to that cell, but if I had to use the arr identifier I should have done it in this way instead

```
*(*(arr+1)) = 12; // arr[1][0]
```

But I don't get why I can't say in this other way instead

```
*(*(arr+8)) = 12;
```

Maybe my knowledge of pointers and two-dimension arrays is that poor, but I'd really like to understand how these kinds of things work.

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: `*(arr+8) = 12; // arr[1][0]` is incorrect. In C, `*(*(arr + i) + j` references the `int` at `a[i][j]`. C knows the length already of the elements and the nested array and takes those sizes into account.

Comment: My bad, I misspelled, I meant *(ptr+8) instead of *(arr+8)

Comment: Yet when I try to read the value stored, it gives me 4

Comment: When you read what value?  Your code doesn't show how you are reading it. If you are reading `*(ptr+8)` you are reading some value outside of the array, someplace else in memory, whatever that is. Probably something further up the stack that just doesn't happen to cause an access violation.

Comment: Edited again, I'm reading the element at arr[1][0]

Comment: Are you saying that if you do `*(*(arr+1)) = 12` then you are getting 4 when you read `[1][0]`?

Comment: Welp, you did not say that statement was wrong, thus I think it is right (I even tried), but no, I meant the first code. If i type *(ptr+8) = 12; and then print the value of arr[1][0] it gives me 12, as well for the second piece of code (*(*(arr+1)) = 12;); but it doesn't for the last one

Comment: `*(*(arr+8)) = 12;` is beyond the length of the array.  `arr+N` gives you the *Nth* row of arr.   Your arr has only 6 rows.   `ptr` is just a simple array of ints; so `ptr + 8` is the first element in the second row; `ptr + 16` is the first element in the third row.   It can really help to print out the addresses generated by the various expressions, and study what goes on.

Comment: @std124_lf yes, sorry, I was not clear on that point and didn't read what you had carefully. Your results writing `*(ptr+8)` makes sense. Mevets has explained the difference.

Comment: @mevets ok, but why is it beyond the length? what does the identifier arr point to? For sure not to arr[0][0], cause if it was, the first, the second and the third code should produce the same result

Comment: So is ptr just an escamotage to avoid dereferencing the array two times while using pointer arithmetic?

Comment: I think the key to understanding this is to realize that `arr` does not decay to an `int **`.  Instead it decays to a pointer to an `int[8]`. So `arr + 1` does not increment `arr` by the size of an int, but by the size of 8 ints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array, whether one-dimensional, two-dimensional, or more, does not point to anything. It **is** a set of objects of the same type in contiguous memory.

After `int arr[6][8];`, `arr` is an array of 6 arrays of 8 `int`. If each `int` uses four bytes, then the entire array uses 6•8•4 = 192 bytes in memory, and `sizeof arr` will evaluate to 192, because `arr` **is the array**, and `sizeof` gives the size of its operand.

When you use `arr` in an expression, it will be **automatically converted** to a pointer to its first element, except when it is the operand of `sizeof` or of unary `&`.<sup>1</sup> Because `arr` is an array of arrays, its first element is also an array. The first element of `arr` is `arr[0]`, which is an array of 8 `int`. So, in `arr+1`, `arr` is converted to a pointer to its first element. That pointer is `&arr[0]`, the address of `arr[0]`.

When an integer, say *n* is added to a pointer, the result points to *n* further elements long in the array. So, when we add 1 to `&arr[0]`, we get `&arr[1]`. Thus, in `arr+1`, `arr` is automatically converted to `&arr[0]`, producing `&arr[0]+1`, and then the addition produces `&arr[1]`.

Thus, `arr+1` is `&arr[1]`, which is also the place where `arr[1][0]` is. (Note that while `&arr[1]` and `&arr[1][0]` point to the same place in memory, they have different types, so the compiler treats them differently when doing arithmetic with them.)

After `int *ptr = &arr[0][0];`, `ptr` of course points to `arr[0][0]`. Then `ptr+8` points to where `arr[0][8]` would be if there were such an element. Of course, there is no, since `arr[0]` has only elements from `arr[0][0]` to `arr[0][7]`. `ptr+8` points one beyond `arr[0][7]`.

That pointer arithmetic is defined by the C standard; you are allowed to point “one beyond the last element.” However, that is only a placeholder pointer, useful for arithmetic and comparisons. The C standard does not happen when you dereference the pointer, with `*(ptr+8)`.

We know that `arr[1][0]` is in the place where `arr[0][8]` hypothetically would be. However, the C standard does not give us rules that say we can definitely use `*(ptr+8)` to access `arr[1][0]`. So that code does not have behavior defined by the C standard. Many compilers will treat it has accessing `arr[1][0]`, though.

As you note, `*(*(arr+1))` can be used to access `arr[1][0]`. The way this works is:

- `arr` is automatically converted to `&arr[0]`.
- Adding 1 gives `&arr[1]`.
- `*` dereferences `&arr[1]`, producing `arr[1]`.
- `arr[1]` is an array, so it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. This produces `&arr[1][0]`.
- `*` dereferences `&arr[1][0]`, producing `arr[1][0]`.

In contrast, `*(*(arr+8))` does not work to access `arr[1][0]`:

- `arr` is automatically converted to `&arr[0]`.
- Adding 8 gives `&arr[8]`.

Now we are well beyond where `arr` ends. `arr` has only elements from `arr[0]` to `arr[5]`, so `arr[8]` is beyond the end.

Note that adding 8 to `&arr[0]` moved the pointer by **8 elements of the `arr` array**, not by 8 eleemnts of the `arr[0]` array. That is, it moved it by 8 arrays of 8 `int`, not by 8 `int`. That is because the **type** of `&arr[0]` is “pointer to array of 8 `int`”, not “pointer to `int`”.

When you add 8 to a “pointer to `int`”, you move it by 8 `int`. When you add 8 to a “pointer to an array of 8 `int`”, you move it by 8 arrays of 8 `int`.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> All arrays are automatically converted like this, and there is one more exception for string literals. When a string literal, which is an array of characters, is used to initialize a character array, it is not automatically converted to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
*(*(arr+8)) = 12;
```

translates to

```
arr[8][0] = 12;
```

which is outside of the array bounds. The behavior of writing outside array bounds is undefined - it may crash immediately, it may corrupt data in the stack, or it may work without any apparent issues.

Remember that unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" is converted, or "decays", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.  The expression `arr` has type "6-element array of 8-element array of `int`; under most circumstances, it "decays" to type "pointer to 8-element array of `int`", or `int (*)[8]`.

Adding 1 to a pointer value yields a pointer to the next *object* of the pointed-to type.  If the expression `arr` yields a pointer to an 8-element array of `int`, then the expression `arr + 1` yields a pointer to to the next *8-element array of `int`* immediately following.  Thus

```
      int          int *        int (*)[8]
+–––+ 
|   | arr[0][0]    p            arr
+–––+      
|   | arr[0][1]    p+1 
+–––+
|   | arr[0][2]    p+2
+–—–+
 ...
+–—–+
|   | arr[0][6]    p+6
+–––+
|   | arr[0][7]    p+7
+–––+
|   | arr[1][0]    p+8          arr+1
+—––+
```

This is why `*(*(arr + 8)) == arr[8][0]` - `arr + 8` yields a pointer to the 8’th 8-element array of `int` following `arr`.  This is why `*(*(arr + 1)) == arr[1][0]`.